# Large Data streaming from sql server through WCF to client

Tags: sql-server, wcf, streaming, large-files

What are  possible ways of storing large data file( CSV filesaround 1 GB)  using SQL database and streaming that data from Database using WCF to the client(without fetching the complete data in memory )?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to store 1GB CSV files in a RDBMS?  This sounds like a design problem.  I suppose you could use `FILESTREAM` and pull it from the directory...

Comment: @DanField Beside using Database  not able to figure out ny other way . Just a brief overview of my usecase :- have a web aplication that could be hosted on multiple servers at customer end behind Load Balancer(NLB) & with the web aplication we have windows service that generate the csv file on request .Storing this file on hard disk of installed server creates problem when request for download come  since we are not sure at what node(behind NLB) does the file got created and request for download may be redirected to some other node.Can't use network path(security issues).What u suggest?-Thanks

Comment: @DanField by file stream u mean SQL FileStream. Is it possible to directly stream data through sql using WCF while using filestream?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few issues to take into account here:

- The size of the data you actually want to return
- The structure of that data (or lack thereof)
- The place to store that data behind your NLB
- Returning that data to the consumer.

From your question, it sounds like you want to store 1 GB of structured (CSV) data and stream it to the client.  If you really are generating and then serving a 1GB file (and don't have much metadata around it), I'd go for using a FTP/SFTP server (or perhaps a Network file share, which can certainly be secured in a variety of ways).

If you need to store metadata about the file that goes beyond its file name/create time/location, then SQL might be a good option, assuming you could do one of the following:

- store the CSV data in tabular format in the database
- Use `FILESTREAM` and store the file itself

[Here is a decent primer on FILESTREAM from SimpleTalk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/).  You could then use the `SqlFileStream` to help stream the data from the file itself (and SQL Server will help maintain transactional consistency for you, which you may or may not want), an example of which is present in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724(v=vs.110).aspx).  The relevant section is here:

```
private static void ReadFilestream(SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStringBuilder.ToString()))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP(1) Photo.PathName(), GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT() FROM employees", connection);

        SqlTransaction tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        command.Transaction = tran;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Get the pointer for the file
                string path = reader.GetString(0);
                byte[] transactionContext = reader.GetSqlBytes(1).Buffer;

                // Create the SqlFileStream
                using (Stream fileStream = new SqlFileStream(path, transactionContext, FileAccess.Read, FileOptions.SequentialScan, allocationSize: 0))
                {
                    // Read the contents as bytes and write them to the console
                    for (long index = 0; index < fileStream.Length; index++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(fileStream.ReadByte());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you do choose to store it in tabular format you can use typical `SqlDataReader` methods, or perhaps some combination of `bcp` and .NET helpers.

You should be able to combine that last link with [Microsoft's remarks on streaming large data over WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the desired result.

Comment: I would save the file as BLOB, you don't need to store it to the table exactly if you don't want to (more work to do)